# Map implementaion using arraylist as value

Tags: arraylist, dictionary, iterator, key

I am using Maps in my code for the first time, hence require some inputs from you experts.

My requirement is I have to check two different tables from database. Value from First table will be used as **Key** and Value for second table will be used as **Value** for the key.

Each key will have multiple values, so I will be storing all values against each key in a arraylist i.e. my Map will be like **MAP.**

*Now, my issue is following:*

1. I don't know the total no. of keys, so I can't create arraylist objects in advance. How to manage this?
2. How can I check if key exists in map such that if it exists then I have to updated the arraylist corresponding to it only. And if it doesn't exist then create new key, create arraylist corresponding to it, populate arraylist with the value.
3. Finally I have to iterate whole map and use the key and values.

How can it be implemented? Am I following the right approach? if not what is a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With lists in Java you do not need to know the size up front.  That is a requirement for Arrays.  Therefore just create your Map

   Map> myMap = new HashMap<>();
2. This should work

   if (myMap.containsKey(someKey)) {
     myMap.get(someKey).add(someValue); // adds a value to the list that already is in the map
   } else {
     myMap.put(someKey, Arrays.asList(someValue)); // which inserts a new key/value 
   }
3. If you need to iterate over all values in the list then you need a nested for loop

   for (Map.Entry> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
     // your key = entry.getKey()
     for (ValueType value : entry.getValue()) {
       // use your value 
     }
   }

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Scott.
I am using the same approach except in Step 2. In step 2, I have used:
--LoopStarts
ArrayList<String> values = map.get(somekey);
if (values==null) {
    values = new ArrayList<String>();
    map.put(user, values)
}
values.add(someValue);
--LoopEnds

Actually, I read somewhere that it is more performance efficient. Is it so?

Comment: Yes.  That is probably more efficient.  My code has one extra check (containsKey()).  Your code splits the list initialization and put into two statements.  I believe they are identical other than that.